# Azure Active Directory: where are credentials checked for Guest Microsoft Account users?

Tags: azure-active-directory

When one has an Azure AD Tenancy (eg: foobar.com) and invites a Guest Microsoft (Personal) Account (eg: foo@gmail.com), where are the password credentials checked?

I'm asking because I could have sworn that in 2017, when you invited a Guest, it would say Type=Microsoft Account, and the password was matched against the password that Microsoft Account knew.

But today in 2018, my personal MA account was invited to my Organisation's Domain, as a Guest, and when I accepted, I was asked to create a password (didn't understand why it didn't see that it was a Microsoft Account, and leave it at that) I gave it a different password than what I gave Microsoft Account), and now, when I sign in it is asking for the newly created password....not Microsoft Account.

Looking over the infrastructure specialist's shoulder, I see the Type=Azure Application Directory (not Microsoft Account).

It sort of appears that the the Organisation become my 'home' AAD Tenant. And that would be a personal fiasco, as where I work, they are so locked down, can't reset passwords, etc....

I guess the question is: 
a) Is Microsoft Account being deprecated and it's all moving towards the use of B2B between Organisation's AADs?
b) if not, could someone explain what's going on (how AAD thinks)
c) how can I get my organisation, when they invite me, pass through credential checking to the Microsoft Account IdP, as it used to.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: This is not an expected issue . Usually, it won't aks you to create a new password. It will just use the MA to sign in. Can you try to invite another account which has been one directory?