# Azure Active Directory: Is Guest only for B2B?

Tags: azure-active-directory

In AAD, one could

- add new Users to the same Domain
- add Guests:

  - from other AAD Tenancies, passing through credential verification to the other Tenancy
  - from Microsoft Account users, passing through credential checking to live.com

But I'm noticing today although it still accepts to invite MA users, when they sign in, they are asked to create a Password.

From then on, they are shown the usual "Do you want to use your personal account or org/school account".

1. Is this a new change?
2. Should be no longer be inviting personal accounts, and stick to only inviting users within other Tenancies (so they don't get asked whether to use Pers/Work account when signing in)?
3. What happens when they create a company around their own email...will they be able to wrest back resolution of the credentials -- or will it always stay with the first tenant that imported a personal account!?

Thanks for help understanding how this aspect of Azure AD works.

Comment: Um.. this is not an expected issue . Usually, it won't aks you to create a new password. It will just use the MA to sign in.  Can you try to invite  another account which has been one directory?

Comment: This is pretty similar to your previous question which you posted 2 hours before this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267359/azure-active-directory-where-are-credentials-checked-for-guest-microsoft-accoun.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Active Directory: where are credentials checked for Guest Microsoft Account users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267359/azure-active-directory-where-are-credentials-checked-for-guest-microsoft-accoun)